# Start application with parameters on Windows start

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup, startup

I am trying to have my application automatically launch and run the log-in logic when Windows starts up.

I've got it working with a shortcut in the startup folder with parameters but I was wondering if there is some way to set a registry key that can start my program and pass it parameters like a shortcut would?

I'm using Inno Setup for the installer and I was using this line:

```
Name: "{commonstartup}\AppNameHere"; Filename: "{app}\AppNameHere.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/login"`
```

But I want to be able to instead use a registry entry like so:

```
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "AppNameHere"; ValueData: """{app}\AppNameHere.exe"""; \
    Flags: uninsdeletevalue`
```

I thought there would be some way to specify parameters for the startup but I cannot find anything on the Inno Setup website other than what I already found out about adding the registry key itself from http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?startwithwindows

Does anyone have experience with adding registry keys and starting applications with parameters on Windows startup?

Comment: Just include your parameter in ValueData, separated by a space - after the quote that belongs to the path.

Comment: @Greg Are you just saying that because I tagged this C# or is that specific to InnoSetup? The code snippet above is directly from their knowledge base, so I assume it should work fine..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I think this will work then `Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "AppNameHere"; ValueData: """{app}\AppNameHere.exe"" /login"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue`

Comment: I'm saying because you tagged C#.  When you call C# Assemblies to manipulate the Registry it can be finicky. Yes, that should work I believe.

Comment: @Zack - Yes, that's what I was thinking.

Comment: I added the registry key with regedit and it works, so I'm saying this is solved. If you want to create an answer for me to mark, I will mark it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can include parameters in `ValueData`, separated with a space from each other and from the executable path. E.g.:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "AppNameHere"; \
    ValueData: """{app}\AppNameHere.exe"" /login"
```

Comment: This works, needs to be inside a `[Registry]` section. And, of course, the user will need admin privileges for the installer.

Comment: @auto - Thanks. I think it should be kind of obvious where the statement goes, the question already has the registry key - this answer just improves it. Not criticizing your comment, but the edit may not be necessary. This Q/A is not meant to be a tutorial after all. Just my opinion..

Comment: I came in from a google search and didn't know about the `[Registry]` section, so it wasn't obvious to me. Took me an extra search to find it. I imagine others starting out with InnoSetup would be in the same position.