# Creating shortcut in startup folder using Inno setup

Tags: java, windows, inno-setup, desktop-application, launch4j

I'm developing a java application that i want to run on startup. I used launch4j to create .exe file and Inno setup to generate installer. Is there any way to create a shortcut in the startup folder using Inno setup ??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `[Icons]` section you can use constants `{userstartup}` or `{commonstartup}`.

For example:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{userstartup}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works ! :D

Comment: The "start up" folder is deprecated, use registry `Run` entry instead. See [Start application with parameters on windows start](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15123421/850848).

Comment: Is it missing a quote after MyProg.exe or no?

Comment: @Mark Dodsons yes there was.  Just recently provided an edit.